# How to hide serious business logic in JS file

Tags: javascript

In our recent applications we are using lots of AJAX in JS files to avoid frequent postbacks. But I'm worried about the public getting into some of our business logic by just checking the JS file. They can also alter the data being sent to the server using firebug or such features. So how can we avoid this scenario and protect our code from being easily visible to the world.

In this case, the public can see the server side function, parameters etc easily. So how can we avoid this headache to some extent.

```
var param = { id: id };
var param = JSON.stringify(param);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "qmaker.aspx/deleteQuestion",
    data: param,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    global: false,
    beforeSend: function () {
        $.blockUI({
            message: '<h3>Deleting Question..<br><small>Please wait for a moment...</small></h3>'
        });
    },
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.d == 1) {
            var n = noty( type: 'success', text: 'Question Deleted successfully.', /* ... */)
            var oTable = $('#table_question).DataTable();
            var row = oTable.row($(that).parents('tr:first'));
            /* ... */
```

Comment: No matter what you do it will still be visible to the public.

Comment: Are you worried about them seeing your code, or are you worried about them manipulating the data being sent?  Your question partly reads like the latter.  _Never_ trust _any_ data sent from the client - no matter what you do, it may have been manipulated.

Comment: Not fool-proof but what about minifying?

Comment: If you are scared about people guessing your business logic based on your front-end JS, then you should move some of this logic to the back-end and keep the front-end treatment minimal. In your front-end, just send what needs to be sent, and begin the treatment only in the back-end. Also, back-end should ALWAYS do the same validations as front-end, or else (like you said), people can change the sent data with firebug and crash your back-end, or even worse ...

Comment: Agree with James, always validate on the server side before database transactions

Comment: No matter what you do, someone can easily send a data to your webservice (via Firebug, CURL or whatever) and "pretend" to be a request from your browser. You must always avalidate your data on the server side. As for exposing logic on JS: I don't see any alarming logic being exposed here. Maybe you would like to point out what's been bothering you?

Comment: @Java_User Minification is about as useful as a spoon to protect you from bullets

Comment: Its a client side script, so you can minify it to make it harder to read but you will never be able to make it so the user can't see/edit the requests.

Comment: @DenysSéguret : True that. there seems to be no other way to hide the client side code whatsoever. Period!

Comment: I reject your javascript file and substitute my own tool to send arbitrary HTTP requests.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Yea, I worried about both.. So I was just thinking any features like any dynamic loading of JS logic from server temporarly via some ajax method and after the execution it should get expire..

Comment: if you send it to the client, at any point in time, they have it.

Comment: Disappointing.. I didnt understand what wrong in the question to negative vote it..

Comment: Oh and... did you really post here a screenshot of your source code? Is it so that we can't read all of it, or so that we can't copy it easily?

Comment: @JanDvorak Its not so serious code I shared about.. I was just sharing it as a sample to consider how easily it is visible for the public from the JS file.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't get to pick what the client sends you. I can submit forms without even reading your HTML.

You also don't get to pick what, out of what you send to the client, the client may or may not read. You sent me a JS file, it's out of your hands now.

In traditional programs, you'd be able to relatively safely sell programs by compiling them, because the original source code was unrecoverable<sup>to some definitions of unrecoverable</sup>.

With JavaScript, you send your code to the browser, and ask them nicely to execute it. You can't expect the browser not to read all of the code, right? So why can you expect the same of the user, who is using the browser to view your page?

---

Make sure you application is secure and airtight **even if details about your business logic are leaked**. A good security stands strong even if *everything about the system is known to an attacker*, including the source code and the database structure.

#### Then again

You don't need to expose the inner workings of the server to JavaScript. The "code" you posed doesn't really reveal anything in terms of how the server works, all I know is that there's a page on qmaker.aspx that supports the `deleteQuestion` path, and when I hit that, with an ID, that question will be deleted. It's now up to **you** to think what an attacker might do with this information, and seal any attack vectors.

Comment: @Sajad I haven't found anything under my profile with `union` in it. So it's probably not me. You should post a question on [meta].

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make it safe you should implement authentication and tokenized requests. This way it doesn't matter if the public see the requests, they will not be able to make successful requests without being authenticated and having a valid token.

Edit below: to provide some extra information.

Surely in your applications you implement some kind of login so users are authenticated and allowed (or forbidden) to use certain parts of your application.

When a user logs in, you could generate a (temporary) token on the server side, store it and pass it back to the user through browser session or similar. Then pass the token as a parameter to the ajax calls.

```
$ajax(url, {
    data: {
        token: session.token,
        action: 'delete',
        id: entryID
    }
}
```

The server will check if the token has been passed and it's valid against the db records. If it is it will just perform the requested operation and return a reply, or it could just return a 401 (unauthorized) error..

If you want something more advanced and perhaps safer, you could search for oauth 2.0 authentication.